# In mongodb I would like to get a count of Exit pages where it was the last page in the session based on concurrent timestamp

Tags: mongodb

I have a 'Session' collection from what I would like to get a count of Exit pages where it was the last page in the session based on concurrent timestamp.

```json
{
    "_id" : "51D0DF0B0714F3F3B0A0762092BD5993_tlpns1c2b1",
    "loginId" : "-19015907",
    "pages" : {
      "consumermx" : {
        "ClientA" : {
            "activity_earnActivity" : NumberLong(1378086283000),
            "memberProfile_editAccountProfile" : NumberLong(1378086286000),
            "memberDashboard_editDashboard" : NumberLong(1378086282000)
                    }
                     }
              }
}

{
    "_id" : "E447A3356202AFFB2B67908895EFC191_tlpns1c6b16",
    "loginId" : "-22851219",
    "pages" : {
      "consumermx" : {
        "ClientA" : {
            "item_editNewSearchByCategory" : NumberLong(1378086288000),
            "memberProfile_editAccountProfile" : NumberLong(1378086345000),
            "memberProfile_editPreferencesAssociation" : NumberLong(1378086279000),
            "ssoClient_login" : NumberLong(1378086225000)
                    }
                     }
              }
}
```

Here is what I tried but didn't work:

```javascript
db.Session.aggregate ([
        {$match: {"pages.consumermx.NFCU.memberProfile_editAccountProfile": 
                     {$gte : 1378353600000, $lte : 1378440000000}}},
        {$sort: {"pages.consumermx.NFCU.memberProfile_editAccountProfile": -1}},
        {$limit: 1},
        {$group: { _id: null, count: { $sum: 1 }}}
])
```

Comment: Whats a concurrent timestamp?

Comment: I'd guess that it's supposed to be "curent".

Comment: I meant the format of the timestamp. For example 1378086225000 mean "09/01/2013 21:43:45"

Comment: You'll likely need to use the aggregation framework. Have you tried that yet?

Comment: Here is what I tried but didn't work:

Comment: db.Session.aggregate ([{$match: {"pages.consumermx.NFCU.memberProfile_editAccountProfile": {$gte : 1378353600000, $lte : 1378440000000}}},
                    {$sort: {"pages.consumermx.NFCU.memberProfile_editAccountProfile": -1}},
      {$limit: 1},
      {$group: { _id: null, count: { $sum: 1 }}}])

Comment: It's next to impossible to decrypt your question: the json formatting is broken, the field `NFCU` is mentioned in the query but not in the example json. It's not clear how the 'exit page' is determined and why `ClientA` wouldn't need an array of events, if those are events. Even less clear is the expected outcome. The aggregation query, as it stands, looks complicated but is not more than a slow count, if even a count.